# How can I stop code from happening in VBscript

Tags: vbscript

I want when the user press the cancel button the code stops
here is the code

```
X=MsgBox("hi",0+22,"Discord")
yay=X=MsgBox("Do you want help?", 1+32, "Discord")
if yay= Cancel then
X=MsgBox("closing...", 0+32, "Discord")
End if
X=MsgBox("a wild messege has appered", 1+32, "Discord")
X=MsgBox("error the messege could not load", 0+16, "Discord")
X=MsgBox("do you want to restart?", 0+32, "Discord")
X=MsgBox("we found a virus you need to restart your computer", 0+32, "oops..")
X=MsgBox("Please restart your computer", 0+32, "Windows")
```

If you have any suggestions tell me

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask] a Good Question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have changed your code slightly

```
Dim X As Integer
Dim yay As Integer

Do
    
X = MsgBox("hi", 0 + 22, "Discord")
yay = X = MsgBox("Do you want help?", 1 + 32, "Discord")

If yay = 0 Then
X = MsgBox("closing...", 0 + 32, "Discord")
Exit Do
End If

X = MsgBox("a wild messege has appered", 1 + 32, "Discord")
X = MsgBox("error the messege could not load", 0 + 16, "Discord")
X = MsgBox("do you want to restart?", 0 + 32, "Discord")
X = MsgBox("we found a virus you need to restart your computer", 0 + 32, "oops..")
X = MsgBox("Please restart your computer", 0 + 32, "Windows")
    
Loop While 1 = 0
```

Comment: Get out the first too lines and you are done